# How to insert Update Date in a Tableau dashboard title box

Tags: tableau-api

How can I insert date to refresh automatically on a Tabelau dashborad published online?  I figured out how to do it in worksheets by inserting Update Date in the title, but I want to do this in the Dashboard title box, where I do not see the option.

Comment: Is this date tied to a database value or is it the current date/time?

Comment: Thanks for responding!  Not the database value, but the time when the data was last refreshed.  Since I wrote the question, I now created a worksheet with just the title where I inserted "Update Data Time" from the drop down, then floated it to my dashboard top right corner.  But I think it's giving me logging in time instead, not data refresh.  I know the IT folks are refreshing the table every 30 minutes, but this is stuck at the time I logged in.  Any thoughts?  There must be a way to show the Time of last refresh?  Thanks for much!

Answer (score 2):

There are three options I can think of.

1. Create a calculated field in your data that shows the value of the Now() function. Float that in its own worksheet like you did. But, you'll want to consider turning on the auto-refresh for the workbook so that the date/time is updated occasionally. By default it will show Now() from whenever the Tableau data source was last refreshed.
2. If using a data extract, look in Tableau's Postgres database for the last refresh time and put that on a worksheet and float it in a dashboard.
3. If you data source has a last updated time that you could calculate, such as max(created_on), create a worksheet with that and float it in the dashboard.

I've used all three methods, it just depends on the specific needs. It will have to be worksheet based though; a dashboard title box cannot show anything bound to data. Use the floating worksheet to make it look like it's part of the title.

Comment: Thanks!  Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Please find http://russellchristopher.me/youdidwhat/autoload.html link it will refresh on per 1 secound data will change OR refresh automatically Try this.

I hope it will help on your work....

Thanks